# SaltStack: No usable error message if dpkg fails

Tags: saltstack

I get this message from `salt-ssh`

---

```
      ID: apache
Function: pkg.installed
  Result: False
 Comment: Problem encountered installing package(s). Additional info follows:

          errors:
              - Running scope as unit: run-r62a347a4ff4d4aa398bd0b516ba4fb59.scope
                E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
 Started: 15:47:16.154590
Duration: 9726.732 ms
 Changes:
```

How to get see the root of the problem?

I already used `--log-level=all`, but still can't see a meaningful error message.

I don't think that `dpkg` silently exists with an error code without printing some message on stdout/stderr.

I guess that salt-stack drops the important error message somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked together this wrapper:

https://github.com/guettli/wrap_and_log_calls

Now I run `salt-ssh` again and searched for non zero "ret:" lines.

I found:

```
Parent: python2.7 /var/tmp/.root_dcdf8c_salt/salt-call --retcode-passthrough --local --metadata --out json -l quiet -c /var/tmp/.root_dcdf8c_salt -- state.pkg /var/tmp/.root_dcdf8c_salt/salt
_state.tgz test=None pkg_sum=7683cfdcaf0ef6b6c907889fab738da83b6f897fe02387251db02a25f541e4ca hash_type=sha256
Parent: /usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confdef install openssl-foo-bar-user.cert
Parent: python /usr/bin/dpkg --force-confold --force-confdef --status-fd 70 --no-triggers --unpack --auto-deconfigure /var/cache/apt/archives/openssl-foo-bar-user.cert_1-2_all.deb
stdout:
(Reading database ... 365773 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openssl-foo-bar-user.cert_1-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking openssl-foo-bar-user.cert (1-2) ...


stderr:
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openssl-foo-bar-user.cert_1-2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/ssl/server/foo-bar_user.pem', which is also in package server-certificates-user 2-2.1
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma write error: Broken pipe
dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openssl-foo-bar-user.cert_1-2_all.deb
```

Now I know the problem is with the custom (non pulic) dpkg `openssl-foo-bar-user.cert`

It would be very kind, if salt-stack could tell me the real reason immediately the next time. It is not difficult, just don't hide stdout/stderr :-)